# SSRS Multi Level List

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to set up a list with multiple levels. I am having troubles setting up my data to do so and was wondering if someone could provide some suggestions.

My List of data:

```
| Part # | Previous Part # |
----------------------------
Part1
Sub-Part1         Part1
Sub-Sub-Part1     Sub-Part1
Part2
Sub-Part2         Part2
Part3
Part4
Part5
Sub-Part5         Part5
```

What I am looking for is a list like below:

```
Part1
  Sub-Part1
     Sub-Sub-Part1
Part2
  Sub-Part2
Part3
Part4
Part5
  Sub-Part5
```

What I am currently getting in SSRS is an exact copy of my list of data. The Part# shows up multiple times for each assembly.

How would I set up my data in order to achieve the result described above?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is SSRS 2008 or above, you can use [Hierarchy Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) to achieve this.

Some sample data:

[image]

As per the MSDN article, set up a group to be based on *Part*, and set its **Recursive parent** to be *ParentPart*:

[image]

[image]

I have a simple table based on this:

[image]

To get the **Padding**, set the *Part* textbox **Left Padding** value to be expression-based:

[image]

```
=CStr(2 + (Level()*10)) + "pt"
```

Looks like your requirement:

[image]